# Nomination texts are padded to the left

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election

Nomination texts have padding on the left hand side:

[image]

does this serve a purpose?

Comment: There's not enough open space on that page, obviously. (+1 for the hand-drawn not quite cricles)

Comment: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Comment: [Does this make you feel uneasy?](https://vimeo.com/189919038)

Comment: @Will YES TAKE IT AWAY I CAN'T TAKE IT

Answer (score 5):

In future phases, that space will be used for primary voting arrows and for final election choices. Pretty sure it's there to keep consistency between the pages.

The position of the comments has always irritated me, though.